# Java : Get Maven 'execution' status

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I have the following plugin block in my pom.xml file which is executing fine.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <mainClass>com.capco.qa.common.utils.TestDriveFileGenerator</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Can I get the status of the above main class execution inside my Java program ? Basically, I want to us its status in an if..else block to decide which configuration file to be used.

Comment: What do you mean by status? Do you mean the exit code?

Comment: What exactly is „_my Java program_“? Where is it invoked and when?

Comment: @Tunaki : By 'Status' I meant, the main method inside 'TestDriveFileGenerator' has been executed or not. I want to get this status, and if its executed the I would look for a configuration file which is created in its main method. If not, I will use the default configuration file. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @GeroldBroser, I have webdriver framework files getting executed once the configuration files are generated by the 'main' method of TestDriveFileGenerator. So, I wanted to make sure that if 'main' of TestDriveFileGenerator is actually executed, so that the further class can look for the respective configuration files.